# SKlearn: load trainning data by reading multiple files in a directory

Tags: python-2.7, vector, similarity

I can input test data from a single file without any problem. However, whenever I try to input data from mulitiple files in a directory, I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'. Please see my codes below, I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA

import os
path = "C:\zircon"

def radfil():
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        current = os.path.join(path, file)
        if os.path.isfile(current):
            data = open(current, "rb").read()
            print data

train_set = [radfil()]
test_set = ["The sun in the sky is bright."]
stopWords = stopwords.words('english')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopWords, min_df=1)
#print vectorizer
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
#print transformer

trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
testVectorizerArray = vectorizer.transform(test_set).toarray()
print 'Fit Vectorizer to train set', trainVectorizerArray
print 'Transform Vectorizer to test set', testVectorizerArray
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire stack trace please?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your error is being caused by trying to do a lower() operation in a variable of None type. Maybe this is happening when at

```
trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
```

The radfil() will return a None type. Try combining the data from the files and adding a return statement to radfil().
That's about all I can do without a full stack trace.